# How to draw BPMN annotations and groups in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am new to draw.io and am trying to use it to sketch a BPMN diagram. As of now, the only thing I can't find in the menus are Annotations and Group artifacts.

[image: annotations and groups]

Is there any way to draw these in draw.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days draw.io has a "BPMN" template, and "BPMN General/Gateways/Events" Shape catalogues. The Annotation and Group are in "BPMN General". Groups work fine but...

The design of the Annotation shape has a flaw: the text isn't contained inside the annotation bracket. It looks like this:

[image: What Text Annotation Looks Like After typing in it]

Left or right justifying the text doesn't really help. I'm now looking into how to edit the style to fix this.

Please chime in if you have a better workaround to make the above look like this automatically:

[image: How a text annotation should look]

(I did this by dragging a text field over the text annotation object.)

Comment: Just checked and they have fixed the annotation issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can find

[image]     in Flowchart Menu

**and**

[image]     in Texts and images Menu

If still you unable to find these options, You can draw your specific image in paint and you can import the file to your draw.io with the library name

**File -> New Library**

Once you added your library you can able to use this image in your BPMN diagram.

Hope this helps

Comment: I was able do the annotation but was not able to do the group. I also tried adding it as an image but it did not scale well. Is the group artefact hidden or reused in another category?